# Semi-colon erro with php

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code

The VSCode set an erro in a HTML line with PHP code:

```
style="width: <?php echo $percent;?>%"
```

The erro is:

```
semi-colon expected
```

Because %" is not recognize.

The complete code:

```
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
      <div class="card border-left-info shadow h-100 py-2">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
            <div class="col mr-2">
              <div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-info text-uppercase mb-1">Progress</div>
              <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
                <div class="col-auto">
                  <div class="h5 mb-0 mr-3 font-weight-bold text-gray-800"><a href="progress.php"><?php echo $percent;?>%</a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="progress progress-sm mr-2">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: <?php echo $percent;?>%" aria-valuenow="<?php echo $percent;?>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
              <i class="fas fa-tasks fa-2x text-gray-300"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You have a simple syntax error for inline CSS. You need a semi-colon after the percent sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I don't see any declaration of the value of $percentage.
2. You don't need to put ; when calling the php variables inside html tag.

sample:
$percentage = 50;

```
<p><? echo $percentage ?> </p>
```

Comment: Declaration is in my back, with PHP and return a number, like your sample ($percentage = 50;) but the point is: css width need a % and when a put de signal my VSCode show this error.

Comment: @Kim, this is a working code from PHP fiddle (tested)

`<?php

$var = 50;

?>

<html>
    <style>
        p {
            
            width: <?php echo $var ?>%;
        }
    </style>

<body>
    <p>displaying value of percentage from php file/variable: <?php echo $var ?>%</p>
    </body>

</html>
`

Comment: working!!! VS Code show the same erro in IDE but in production its ok now. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You can add quotes to isolate the 'value' of width :

```
style="width: '<?php echo $percent;?>%'"
```

Or like said in you error message, add a semi-colon inside style (but outside php, just after the %) :

```
style="width: <?php echo $percent ?>%;"
```

Comment: Arthur, with this code i can fix the error, but doesn't' work de % in my application. 
width don't understand the %

Comment: I think that your class "progress" (which wraps the progress-bar) need to have a clear width value. This way, the percentage of "progress-bar" will know what it refers to